# Patching values in FormBuilder form and watching for changes causes infinite loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript, ionic2

I have simple Angular FormBuilder form (in Ionic 2 Application) with 3 fields:

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,
    public viewCtrl: ViewController, private builder: FormBuilder) {
        this.form = this.builder.group({
            startDate: ['', Validators.required],
            endDate: ['', Validators.required],
            count: [0, Validators.required], //diff in days
        });
}
```

my template:

```
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label floating>Start</ion-label>
    <ion-datetime formControlName="startDate" [min]="today_iso" displayFormat="DD/MM/YYYY" pickerFormat="DD/MM/YYYY">
    </ion-datetime>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label floating>End</ion-label>
    <ion-datetime formControlName="endDate" [min]="today_iso" displayFormat="DD/MM/YYYY" pickerFormat="DD/MM/YYYY">
    </ion-datetime>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label fixed>Count</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="number" formControlName="count" ></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
```

I want to dynamically calculate diff between both dates using moment.js and then modify the form value for count field:

```
this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(data => {
  let startDate = moment(data.startDate);
  let endDate = moment(data.endDate);
  let diff = endDate.diff(startDate, 'days');

  if(diff>0) {
    this.form.patchValue({
      count: diff
    })
  }
});
```

However, its seems that form.patchValue causes another execution of valueChanges.subscribe and I get infinite loop execution (*Maximum call stack size exceeded*). How can I avoid that? Is there better way to modify form values on the fly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you're looking for this:

```
this.form.patchValue({ count: diff }, { emitEvent: false });
```

This way `valueChange` won't be fired

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/uvNbkJTvDzhh4OBja1Yf?p=preview)**

Comment: If I do so, my template wont be updated with new count value I think.